# How to find the mean of this standard distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

Question:
The probability distributions for 2 variables are defined as follows$ X$ ~ $N$$(120, σ^2)$ and $Y$ ~ $N$$(μ, 2σ^2)$ and $P(X < 124)$ = $P(Y > 124$). Calculate $μ$.

I tried this for hours and no result. Since there are 2 unknowns, I tried forming a simultaneous equation. Z-scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W:=(X-120)/\sigma,\,Z:=(Y-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{2})$ so $Z,\,W\sim N(0,\,1)$ and$$P(W<4/\sigma)=P(Z>(124-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{2}))=P(Z<(\mu-124)/(\sigma\sqrt{2})).$$Hence$$\frac{4}{\sigma}=\frac{\mu-124}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\implies\mu=124+4\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Why $P(Z>(124-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{2}))=P(Z<(\mu-124)/(\sigma\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk $P(Z>c)=P(Z<-c)$ for any symmetric distribution of $Z$< including $Z\sim N(0,\,1)$.

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk (If the distribution is symmetric around $0$, as is the case here.)